# How to Check If the Watch App is Installed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, watchkit

Is there a way to check if the user has the Watch App Extension installed in his/her Apple Watch?

I need to add Firebase Events to an Apple Watch App to see how frequent is the Apple Watch App used but as far as I know Firebase is not supported in the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isWatchAppInstalled` instance property of your `WCSession` object to determine if the Watch App is installed or not. It returns a `Bool` value you can use in your code.

More information on this can be found in the developer docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615623-iswatchappinstalled